# Append id from button clicked to an existing JQuery Function that Toggles a Form

Tags: jquery, button, dynamic

I have a table, each row is ended with a dynamically generated button. That button has an id matching the id of the user from the DB. I want to be able to press any of the buttons and pass that id to a script that toggles a form. I just cannot work out how to append the id to an existing script to toggle the form.

So far the code I have is

```
<button type='submit' class='btn btn-success' id='formButton$uid' onclick='myFunction()'>Edit User #$uid</button>
```

&

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#3").click(function() {
    $("#form1").toggle();
  });
});
```

As you see in the code above I have hard coded the id of 3 in but as I say I am looking for that id to take the value, the id, from any of the buttons clicked so if there are 50 buttons they can all toggle the form as the button clicked id will have be appended into the JQuery toggle function.

Answer (score 0):

After a few hours I have managed to add the id to the JQuery.

```
     <form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="POST">
        <input type="submit" name="mybutton" id="1" value="1">
        <input type="submit" name="mybutton" id="2" value="2">
        <input type="submit" name="mybutton" id="3" value="3">
        <input type="submit" name="mybutton" id="4" value="4">
    </form>
```

Then the JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#<?php echo $_POST['mybutton'] ?>").click(function() {
   $("#form1").toggle();
 });
});
```

I don't know if this is the best way of doing the job?

Answer (score 0):

you could hook the on click event on the element name like so

```html
<button type='submit' name="mybutton" Id="#$uid" onclick='myFunction()'>Edit User #$uid</button>
<button type='submit' name="mybutton" Id="#$uid" onclick='myFunction()'>Edit User #$uid</button>
<button type='submit' name="mybutton" Id="#$uid" onclick='myFunction()'>Edit User #$uid</button>
```

```js
$('button[name="mybutton"]').each(function() {
  $(this).click(function() {
    console.log($(this).attr("Id"));
    $("#form1").toggle();
  });
});
```

[https://jsfiddle.net/bjq5drwh/2/]

I hope this helps

Comment: Hi Patrick, I have had a look at your link. The code does the job, particularly the 1st set. Thank you.